# Can I assign an augment to an array directly in bash?

Tags: bash

I would like to assign an augment to an array directly in bash.
Please see following,

```
function chmod_func() {
  local file_path="$1"
  local chmod_options=( ${2:='-R 744'} )  # This line has error.
  sudo chmod "${chmod_options[@]}" "${file_path}"
}

chmod_func "test.txt"
```

The error message is following,

```
$2 : cannot assign in this way
```

If someone knows solutions, please let me know. Thank you very much.

Comment: Which version of bash are you using? The only issue I can see is that you are specifying the option backwards; should be `-R 774`, not `774 -R`...

Comment: @I'L'I : I am so sorry for asking something correct. It also works in my bash. The above code is a part of original code which has an error. I should have test the extracted code. I am sorry again. I will delete this question in 3 minutes.

Comment: @I'L'I : I change my mind I will not delete this question but close it because the answer from cdarke below is useful. It gives solution.

Comment: @I'L'I : I fixed code above to regenerate an error correctly. I notice you in case you have interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the comment from @l'L'l about the order of parameters to `chmod`.

You can set individual elements in a couple of ways.  First the syntax you were trying to use:

```
chmod_options=( [2]='744 -R' ) 
echo ${chmod_options[@]}
echo ${!chmod_options[@]}
```

Gives:

```
744 -R
2
```

But you can simply:

```
chmod_options[2]='744 -R'
```

What is a puzzle is *why* you want to do it.  It does not appear to be useful in any way in the example you give.

What you are not doing here is using the second parameter to the function `$2`, for some reason you are hard-coding the value in the function.  You *cannot* do this:

```
2='744 -R'          # illegal
```

But if you need an array you can do this:

```
chmod_options[2]="$2"
```

or this:

```
chmod_options="$2"
```

Note the *double* quotes used here.

You don't really need an array in your example, here is my version which just uses the parameters:

```
function chmod_func() {
  local file_path="$1"
  shift   # remove the first parameter

  sudo chmod $@ "${file_path}"
}

chmod_func "test.txt" -R 744
```